# Prove the following set is dense?

Tags: calculus

> Prove that the set $Α = \{\frac{m}{2^n}:m\in \mathbb{Z},n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x=\frac{m}{2^n}\in A \subset\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense: $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ such as $a<x<b$. So, $A$ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think you need to check your definition of density. A set $S$ is dense if _every_ nonempty open interval $(a, b)$ intersects $S$. On the other hand, given an arbitrary element $x$ from any old set $X$, we can always find an open interval containing $x$ (for example, $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$), so this is not a special property.

Answer (score 4):

Recall the definition of [dense set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set): we have to show that FOR ALL $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ there EXISTS $x\in A$ such that $a<x<b$. The density of $\mathbb{Q}$ is too weak here because $A$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Hint. If $x=\frac{m}{2^n}$ then  $a<x<b$ is equivalent to
$$2^na<m<2^nb$$
Is there a non negative integer $n$ (large enough) such that the interval $(2^na,2^nb)$ contains an integer $m$?

Answer (score 0):

Choose every possible $m$ of the form $\sum {2^r}$, where $r$´s are less than $n$, and $n$ is travelling through natural numbers. With this you covered an infinite number of numbers in $[0,1]$ and around every one there is an infinite number of other.  Now shift $\sum {2^r}$ by $1$ to arrive at $\sum {2^r}+1$. Shift again. Shift an infinite number of times. Now do all this with $-\sum {2^r}$. Now you´re done.

Comment: You mean $2^{\color{red}{-}r}$?

Comment: @Vim Nope, they must be >0. r´s

Comment: I don't follow. Your first sum would produce positive integers.